# editing table cell xib causes "frame will be different at run time" warning

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I edit a xib for a table cell, I get these warnings afterwards "frame will be different at run time" and I have *not* moved the components. The componest are only one pixel off each time. I know I can temporarily get rid of them by selecting "make frame match constraints", but as soon as I edit it again the same warnings come back. 
Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use constraints, you need to redefine their values after updating any component frame.

Comment: I know that, but I haven't updated any component frame

Comment: @user5664685 so, most likely your xib have ambiguous or conflicting constraints, make sure there's none of these left.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.  You probably have two constraints that are conflicting, but not enough to give you a warning. Check the huggability settings for each constraint. Also see if you have set the height for the entire cell and if your height constraints for each component add up to the total height constraint. If all else fails, remove all constraints and set them again.

Comment: Nope. Even after deleting all constraints and recreating and still back to the origonal problem. The thing is it seems like the components have been moved, because it's saying that they are one pixel off - except that I haven't moved them. At this stage it's looking like a bug in xcode